# np.array MemoryError with tf.data.Dataset.from_generator

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to run this custom Transformer model with my text compression data(Gigaword) https://github.com/Kyubyong/transformer.

I had ran this code with `tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1`/`cuDNN 7.4.1`/`cuda 10.0` on `ubuntu 16.04`.

but keep facing the error like error.

I had successfully run the code on my MacOSX with tensorflow-cpu, however, when I try to train the data on my gpu-server, it returns error.

I tried to change `tf.int32` to `tf.int64` but it doesn't work.(`print(np.intp returns 64`)

I had doubted about `RAM shortage` so track the real-time change of memory with `free -m` command, but it never use up the whole memory (I have `16GB` of memory on my ubuntu server)

What would be the possible problem?

```
INFO:root:# hparams
INFO:root:# Prepare train/eval batches
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zachary/projects/transformer/train.py", line 36, in <module>
    shuffle=True)
  File "/home/zachary/projects/transformer/data_load.py", line 160, in get_batch
    batches = input_fn(sents1, sents2, vocab_fpath, batch_size, shuffle=shuffle)
  File "/home/zachary/projects/transformer/data_load.py", line 125, in input_fn
    args=(sents1, sents2, vocab_fpath))  # <- arguments for generator_fn. converted to np string arrays
  File "/home/zachary/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1461, in from_generator
    generator, output_types, output_shapes, args))
  File "/home/zachary/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 408, in from_generator
    args = tuple(ops.convert_n_to_tensor(args, name="args"))
  File "/home/zachary/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1273, in convert_n_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/home/zachary/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1240, in internal_convert_n_to_tensor
    ctx=ctx))
  File "/home/zachary/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1175, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/home/zachary/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 304, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/home/zachary/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 245, in constant
    allow_broadcast=True)
  File "/home/zachary/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 283, in _constant_impl
    allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
  File "/home/zachary/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 467, in make_tensor_proto
    nparray = np.array(values, dtype=np_dt)
MemoryError
```

Comment: How much RAM does your GPU have and when you checked the memory usage on the CPU side of things, how much memory was being used?

Comment: @rayryeng I had also checked `watch -n 0.1 nvidia-smi` and it never used GPU but the process just used cpu first. My GPU has 8GB of memory.